# Cant find Sdl and Sca pins in lcd display

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, pins

My project is of non contact temperature sensor.I am using RG1602A lcd display and mlx90164 temperature sensor.
But the problem is, there's no sdl , sca pins in my lcd display.

Is there any way, to overcome?

Comment: Why should there be SDA/SCL pins? That display doesn't have an I2C interface, but the standard parallel interface.

Comment: Yes, is there any way I can use other pins to connect with Arduino and sensor.

Comment: Of course you can still connect that display to the Arduino, you just need more pins as with an I2C display. There are tons of tutorials out there about that and the standard LiquidCrystal library supports that communication mode. Have you troed some of those tutorials?

Comment: No, I will check now, tq

Answer (score 1):

You will need an [I2C adapter board](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002070253348.html) like this to interface your LCD 1602 via I2C.